# If "propriety" is from the French for "property", why is it now about proper comportment?

Tags: meaning, etymology, semantic-shift

I was trying to reverse-translate a quote I mistakenly believed to be originally in French that I saw in English, so as to find the source. (It turned out to be from Jeremy Bentham.) In the process, I had to look up the French for *property* (having forgotten the exact word), and discovered that the direct translation would be the feminine noun *propriété*.

Now, this looks suspiciously similar to the English *propriety*, and [a quick search](https://www.google.com/search?q=propriety%20etymology&oq=propriety%20etymology&aqs=chrome..69i57.7052j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8) for the etymology of *propriety* suggests that it indeed is from the French *propriété*. [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/propriety) lists some obsolete uses that are in spirit to the various meanings of *property*. For example:

> The particular character or essence of someone or something; individuality.  [14th-19th c.] . . .
>   A piece of land owned by someone; someone's property. [from 15th c.]

Moreover, [the Etymonline site](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=propriety) gives some potential dates for when use of *propriety* might have shifted more to its current sense of proper character that seems distinct from the any of the meanings of *property*.

This is all good and well, but *why* might have such a shift in usage come up in the first place?

Comment: Note that _proprietary_ retains the central concern with property in the sense of owned things, while _propriety_ links to property in the sense of quality or characteristic.

Comment: http://quod.lib.umich.edu/cgi/m/mec/med-idx?type=id&id=MED34963

Answer (score 2):

The word derives from the Latin *proprietas* which not only had the meaning of property but also took on that word's aspect of particular ownership [1], i.e., peculiarity.  (The same goes for "peculiarity" which is related to the Latin *pecu*, herd (of cattle), the very exemplar of property [2].)  Both words took on the meaning of one's own particular behavior, "propriety" becoming an appropriate standard for behavior, and "peculiarity" becoming a possibly strange behavior.  Given the long co-existence of the two meanings, I doubt you'll find a definitive answer to your question why.

1. *Cassell's New Latin Dictionary*
2. *The Concise Oxford Dictionary of English Etymology*